# operations with structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, intersect

I have a structure 1x300 called `struct` with 3 fields but I'm using only the third field called `way`. This field is, for each 300 lines, a vertor of index.

Here an exemple with 3 lines to explain my problem : I woud like to search if the last index of the first line is present in an other vector (line) of the field `way`.

```
way
[491751 491750 491749 492772 493795 494819 495843 496867]
[491753 491754 491755 491756]
[492776 493800 494823 495847 496867]
```

I tried with intersect function :

```
Inter=intersect(struct(1).way(end), struct.way);
```

but Matlab returns me an error :

```
Error using intersect (line 80)
Too many input arguments.

Error in file2 (line 9)
Inter=intersect(struct(1).way(end), struct.way);
```

I don't understand why I have this error. Any explanations and/or other(s) solution(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the data be defined as

```
st(1).way = [491751 491750 491749 492772 493795 494819 495843 496867];
st(2).way = [491753 491754 491755 491756];
st(3).way = [492776 493800 494823 495847 496867]; % define the data
sought = st(1).way(end);
```

---

If you want to know **which vectors** contain the desired value: pack all vectors into a cell array and pass that to `cellfun` with an anonymous function as follows:

```
ind = cellfun(@(x) ismember(sought, x), {st.way});
```

This gives:

```
ind =
  1×3 logical array
   1   0   1
```

---

If you want to know for each vector **the indices** of the matching: modify the anonymous function to output a cell with the indices:

```
ind = cellfun(@(x) {find(x==sought)}, {st.way});
```

or equivalently

```
ind = cellfun(@(x) find(x==sought), {st.way}, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The result is:

```
ind =
  1×3 cell array
    [8]    [1×0 double]    [5]
```

Or, to exclude the reference vector:

```
n = 1; % index of vector whose final element is sought
ind = cellfun(@(x) {find(x==st(n).way(end))}, {st([1:n-1 n+1:end]).way});
```

Comment: OK thanks for your answer. To go further, is it possible to do the same thing but without taking into account the comparison vector in the results. In the example this would give: `ind = 1 × 2 cell array
    [1 × 0 double] [5] `

Answer (score 0):

You propbably want to use [`ismember`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).

Consider what you are passing to the `intersect`/`ismember` functions too, `struct.way` isn't a valid argument, you may need to loop to iterate over each line of your struct (in this case it would be easier to have a cell array, or matrix with equal length rows).

```
output = zeros(300);
for ii = 1:300
    for jj = 1:300
        if ii ~= jj && ismember(struct(ii).way(end), struct(jj).way)
            output(ii,jj) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Now you have a matrix `output` where the elements which are 1 identify a match between the last element in way in the struct row `ii` and the vector `struct(jj).way`, where `ii` are the matrix row numbers and `jj` the column numbers.